# I want to generate bill of restaurant by multiplying quantity and price how to do this

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

In my code of invoice food name and food price both are showing food name on localhost portal so look into my foreign keys And also guide how to multiply product price and quantity. I am showing you both add product table and invoice table and their forms also look out and guide me for this

models.py

```
class AddFood(models.Model):
    food_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    food_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompRegister, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    res = models.ForeignKey(ResRegister, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.food_name


class GenerateInvoice(models.Model):
    foods_name = models.ForeignKey(AddFood, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='food_n')
    foods_price = models.ForeignKey(AddFood, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='food_p')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompRegister, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    res = models.ForeignKey(ResRegister, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.res, self.foods_name

    def total_price(self):
        return AddFood.food_price * self.quantity
```

forms.py

```
class FoodForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FoodForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['res'].queryset = ResRegister.objects.filter(res=True, company__user_id=user)

    class Meta:
        model = AddFood
        exclude = ['company','price','food']
        fields = '__all__'


class InvoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InvoiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['foods_name'].queryset = AddFood.objects.filter(company__user_id=user)
        self.fields['foods_price'].queryset = AddFood.objects.filter(company__user_id=user)

    class Meta:
        model = GenerateInvoice
        exclude = ['company','res','start_date',]
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def generate_invoice(request):
    u = CompRegister.objects.get(user_id=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InvoiceForm(request.user, request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form_r = form.save(commit=False)
            form_r.company = u
            form_r.save()
            return redirect('company:cart_page')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = InvoiceForm(request.user)
    return render(request, 'comp/generate_invoice.html', {'form': form})
```

generate_invoice.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends 'Comp_base.html' %}
{% block head %}

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Generate Invoice</title>

{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Generate Invoice</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Comment: The modeling looks rather odd. The `GenerateInvoice` has two references to `AddFood`, one for the `name` and one for the `price`? But both are referencing an entire `AddFood` object. It is also "odd" that the `AddFood` itself contains a `Price`. It might be better to have a `Food` model with the name and price, an `Order` which references the `Food`, `Invoice` annd `Company` for example.

Comment: okay Thank you so much i know it reffer whole model that's why i asked this que and you got me good idea thanks